# Unable to get View id from ViewPager which is inside another ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I got three ViewPagers.

1. `MainPager` this one contains all views and both `ScoreboardPager` and `StopwatchPager`
2. `ScoreboardPager` this contains
   a few `TextViews` which act like timers
3. `StopwatchPager` this contains a few `TextViews` which keep track of score

The issue with this is that I'm unable to get any of the `TextViews` from either 2 or 3.

I call `findViewFromId` inside `StopwatchFragment` and `ScoreboardFragment`, like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_stopwatch, container, false);
    MainFragment.StopwatchTimeBlue = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stopwatchTimeBlue);        
    MainFragment.StopwatchTimeOrange = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stopwatchTimeOrange);
    return rootView;
}
```

When I try and assign a value to it, it won't get updated. I assign it like this, inside `MainFragment`.

```
if (blueScore > 0) {
    if (StopwatchTimeBlue != null) {
        Log.i("Timer", String.format("Found stopwatchTimeBlue, value is ", StopwatchTimeBlue.getText().toString()));
        StopwatchTimeBlue.setText(timeInText);
    }
}
```

Any help is welcome

Comment: Why is your code incomplete? ` MainFragment.StopwatchTimeBlue = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stopwatchTimeBlue);
    MainFragment.StopwatchTimeOrange = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.
    `

Comment: Woops, I didn't even notice. I fixed it now

Comment: Why are you using `MainFragment.StopwatchTimeOrange ` ? Why can't you use `StopwatchTimeOrange ` alone?

Comment: I need to use StopwatchTimeOrange in MainFragment

Comment: Use Interface for Each View pager see this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/20412875/4146722

Comment: @PräTîkTank I'm not sure why I would need to use that, my fragments update fine.