# How to refresh RecyclerView in one fragment when data changed in another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment

How do I refresh the data from a local database to RecyclerView when data was successfully submitted? I use the tabs on the application. `2nd-Tab` functions to submit the data, and if successful, the data will be stored in `localDB`.

Data on `localDB` I will present at the `3rd-Tab`.
But what happens, I have to swipe `1st-Tab`, then swipe to the `2nd-Tab` and then swipe to the new `3rd-Tab` data on my `localDB` **successfully displayed**.

If the 2nd-Tab me to submit the data, then I swipe to `3rd-Tab`, the data will **not appear on the list of data**.
How do I get the data directly displayed without the need to swipe to the first `1st-Tab` and then to the `2nd-Tab` and `3rd-Tab` ???
[image: 2nd-Tab]

**MainActivity** :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.bertho.gmyl.fragments.EngagedFragment;
import com.bertho.gmyl.fragments.RequestFragment;
import com.bertho.gmyl.fragments.SigninFragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.engine_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new SigninFragment(), "SIGN-IN");
        adapter.addFrag(new EngagedFragment(), "ENGAGED ID");
        adapter.addFrag(new RequestFragment(), "LOCATION");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

}
```

**EngagedFragment** (2nd-Tab) Form to save data

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bertho.gmyl.R;
import com.bertho.gmyl.model.Engaged;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.bertho.gmyl.realm.RealmHelper;

public class EngagedFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = EngagedFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private EditText nama, email, nohp;
    private Button btnSaveConnection;
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
    private RelativeLayout mRoot;
    private View rootView;
    private String userId;
    private TextView lblNama, lblEmail, lblNohp;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    private RealmHelper realmHelper;


    public EngagedFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_engaged, container, false);

        realmHelper = new RealmHelper(getActivity());

        String appName = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

        loadLocalDB();

        nama = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        email = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        nohp = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtNoHp);

        lblNama = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lblNameval);
        lblEmail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lblEmailval);
        lblNohp = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lblNohpval);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.panelLabelDetail);
        btnSaveConnection = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnEngaged);


        mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("tbl_engaged");

        mFirebaseInstance.getReference("titleapp").setValue(appName);

        mFirebaseInstance.getReference("titleapp").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.e(TAG, "TITLE UPDATED FROM FIREBASE");
                String appTitle = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(appTitle);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "FAILED TO READ TITLE FROM FIREBASE.", error.toException());
            }
        });

        btnSaveConnection.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void showSnack(String notify) {
        mRoot = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.frag_engaged);
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mRoot, notify, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.show();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v.getId() == R.id.btnEngaged) {

            String txtName = nama.getText().toString();
            String txtEmail = email.getText().toString();
            String txtNo = nohp.getText().toString();

            if(txtName.equals("") || txtName.isEmpty()) {
                showSnack("Name must filled");
                nama.requestFocus();
            } else if (txtEmail.equals("") || txtEmail.isEmpty()) {
                showSnack("Email must filled");
                email.requestFocus();
            } else if (txtNo.equals("") || txtNo.isEmpty()) {
                showSnack("No.HP must filled");
                nohp.requestFocus();
            } else {
                createUser(txtName, txtEmail, txtNo);
                saveToLocalDB(txtName, txtEmail, txtNo);
            }
        }
    }

    private void saveToLocalDB(String txtName, String txtEmail, String txtNo) {
        realmHelper.addEngaged(txtName, txtEmail, txtNo);
    }

    private void loadLocalDB() {
        realmHelper.getAllData();
    }

    private void createUser(String name, String email, String nohp) {
        userId = mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey();
        Engaged user = new Engaged(name, email, nohp);
        mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).setValue(user);
        addUserChangeListener();
    }

    private void addUserChangeListener() {

        mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Engaged user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Engaged.class);

                if (user == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ENGAGED DATA IS NULL");
                    return;
                }

                Log.e(TAG, "ENGAGED DATA IS CHANGED!" + user.name + ", " + user.email);

                lblNama.setText(user.name);
                lblEmail.setText(user.email);
                lblNohp.setText(user.nohp);

                //relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                nama.setText("");
                email.setText("");
                nohp.setText("");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.e(TAG, "FAILED TO READ USER", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**RequestFragment** (3rd-Tab) To display localDB

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bertho.gmyl.R;
import com.bertho.gmyl.adapter.AdapterEngaged;
import com.bertho.gmyl.model.ModelEngaged;
import com.bertho.gmyl.realm.RealmHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RequestFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "RequestFragment";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private View rootView;
    private ArrayList<ModelEngaged> data;
    private RealmHelper helper;

    public RequestFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_request, container, false);

        data = new ArrayList<>();
        helper = new RealmHelper(getActivity());

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvArticle);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        setRecyclerView();

        return rootView;
    }

    public void setRecyclerView() {
        try {
            data = helper.findAllArticle();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        AdapterEngaged adapter = new AdapterEngaged(data, new AdapterEngaged.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ModelEngaged item) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "LIST CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            data = helper.findAllArticle();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setRecyclerView();
    }


}
```

Everything went smoothly, it's just that I hope the data can be displayed when the form is submitted and can be directly viewed on the 3rd-Tab

Comment: Try this, use an interface in activity and whenever you submit in the 2nd tab set the callback and in the callback method in activity reload the 3rd fragment's list

Comment: Try to add this line in mainactivity oncreate method after Viewpager initialization:   ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

Comment: Its not effect with `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit();`

Comment: @BerthoJoris did u solve the issue?

Comment: Not yet.... I still try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412379/viewpager-update-fragment-on-swipe

Comment: @BerthoJoris try my soln. let me know if it works

Comment: Ok @Raghavendra I try now..:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

Create an Interface in EngagedFragment 
say,

```
public interface SubmitListener {

    void onSubmit();
}

private SubmitListener onSubmitListener;

public void setSubmitListener(SubmitListener onSubmitListener){
        this.onSubmitListener = onSubmitListener;
}

public SubmitListener getOnSubmitListener(){
        return onSubmitListener;
}
```

In saveToLocalDB(...) method

call

```
onSubmitListener.onSubmit();
```

---

## In MainActivity:

1) Update the below statement:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EngagedFragment.SubmitListener
```

2) Make your **ViewPagerAdapter adapter;** variable as Global variable;

while adding fragment:

```
EngagedFragment engagedFrag = new EngagedFragment();
adapter.addFrag(engagedFrag, "ENGAGED ID");

...
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

3) add this after setting adapter

```
engagedFrag.setSubmitListener(this);
```

4) Override onSubmit() method and try the below code in that method

```
if(viewPager != null){

    if(adapter != null){
        Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(2);
        if(fragment != null){
            RequestFragment requestFragment = (RequestFragment) fragment;
            requestFragment.setRecyclerView();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hai @Raghavendra, when I try your code, I found force close when button save clicked. Error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.bertho.gmyl.fragments.EngagedFragment$SubmitListener.onSubmit()' on a null object reference`

Maybe I miss something. But, when I check, data is saved. Only force close my app.

This is MainActivity : http://pastebin.com/mnMVzkjr

This is EngagedFragment : http://pastebin.com/bWgSGmuk

Comment: Yeaahh.....perfect works..... :)

Thanks @Raghavendra... Btw if I have a another tab, let say 5th tab, I must overide code inside onSubmit method again?

Comment: @BerthoJoris Glad! that helped. I didn't get the qsn dude. Can u rephrase  it what u want to do in 5th tab?

Comment: @BerthoJoris okay if u have similar thing in 5th tab if u want to track some updates create another interface in 5th tab and follow the same steps.

Comment: For example I want the same thing in the fifth tab (same as the third tab now).

Data is submitted will go to the fifth tab without having to swipe it first to a few tabs.

Everything can I modif in the onSubmit method like code above?

Comment: Thank you @Raghavendra ...It's working perfectly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```

if that doesnt help, please check below SO question:

[fragment refresh On Swip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412379/viewpager-update-fragment-on-swipe)

and about : `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);`  this might not work as i found in one of @commonware 's answer's, the following :-

"Does ViewPager require a minimum of 1 offscreen pages
`Yes`. If I am reading the source code correctly, you should be getting a warning about this in LogCat, something like:

```
Requested offscreen page limit 0 too small; defaulting to 1"
```

Comment: Yes..not work with `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);`

Comment: Did you try the linked answer ?

Comment: Not yet...But I will try after this