# How to go listview adapter item click listener to fragment in android?

Tags: java, android, listview, fragment, adapter

I want to go from listview adapter itemview click listener to fragment with extra details that i want to use in that fragment where i go..I use this list view adapter class.I want to go from listview adapter itemview click listener to fragment with extra details that i want to use in that fragment where i go..I use this list view adapter class.

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
    }
  @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView ip;
        TextView port;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        ip = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ip);
        port = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.port);

        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        ip.setText(resultp.get(AddFragment.ip));
        port.setText(resultp.get(AddFragment.port));
        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        // Capture ListView item click
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get the position
                resultp = data.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                // Pass all data rank
                intent.putExtra("ip", resultp.get(AddFragment.ip));
                // Pass all data country
                intent.putExtra("port", resultp.get(AddFragment.port));
                intent.putExtra("uname", resultp.get(AddFragment.uname));
                intent.putExtra("password", resultp.get(AddFragment.password));

                Log.e("uname: ", "> " + resultp.get(AddFragment.uname));
                Log.e("password: ", "> " + resultp.get(AddFragment.password));
                Log.e("ip: ", "> " + resultp.get(AddFragment.ip));
                Log.e("port: ", "> " + resultp.get(AddFragment.port));



                // Pass all data population
                // Pass all data flag
                // Start SingleItemView Class
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }
```

so How i can go to fragment instead of activity.
I want to go in fragment with this put extra detailss. so, How i can go?

Comment: Your fragment has listview and you want details from adapter in fragment? In that case you could use interface as a callback to your fragment

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786356/passing-argument-from-a-fragment-to-its-container-activity/40787805#40787805

Comment: Use a callback (which you can pass to constructor) which communicates back the data to your Activity and then handle the logic to switch fragment from there.

Comment: Yes...My listview in fragment

Comment: give me example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to go listview adapter item click listener in fragment

```
relaylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int
    position, long id) {


            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>)
    relaylist.getItemAtPosition(position);



            Log.e("ip: ", "> " +  o.get("ip"));
            Log.e("port: ", "> " +  o.get("port"));
            Log.e("uname: ", "> " +  o.get("uname"));
            Log.e("password: ", "> " +  o.get("password"));


            ControlFragment fragment = new ControlFragment();

            FragmentTransaction transaction =
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


            Log.e("ip: ", "> " +  o.get("ip"));
            Log.e("port: ", "> " +  o.get("port"));
            Log.e("uname: ", "> " +  o.get("uname"));
            Log.e("password: ", "> " +  o.get("password"));
            transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment );
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("ip", o.get("ip"));
            bundle.putString("port", o.get("port"));
            bundle.putString("uname", o.get("uname"));
            bundle.putString("password", o.get("password"));
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
((Activity) mContext).getFragmentManager();

 itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new CallThisFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity) mContext).getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_activity, fragment).commit();
        }
    });
```

and Use bundle to pass data to a fragment class 
[How to pass Bundle from Fragment to Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063378/how-to-pass-bundle-from-fragment-to-fragment)

Comment: gives me error in first line..                
Fragment fragment = new ControlFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager(); gives me error like incompatible types..required: android.app.fragment found: com.example.lenovo.controlapp.controlframgent
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment).commit();

Comment: please change your fragment imports whether its android.app.Fragment or android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109017/difference-between-android-app-fragment-and-android-support-v4-app-fragment