# FragmentStatePageAdapter ViewPager 5 Tabs Using single Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I am using ViewPager Tablayout to display 5 tabs which when selected fetch data from server to display. The only difference to what data is fetched is the selected Tab. So it would be redundant to have 5 fragments that do same thing. Thus i have implemented to utilise one Fragment as below.

**Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_feed);

    mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    final ViewPager viewPager  = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.blogging);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.tanzania);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.world);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.football);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(R.drawable.coins);
}

private void  setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("edttext", "0");

    NewsFeedTab1 fragObj1 = new NewsFeedTab1();
    fragObj1.setArguments(bundle);

    Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
    bundle2.putString("edttext", "8,15");

    NewsFeedTab1 fragObj2 = new NewsFeedTab1();
    fragObj2.setArguments(bundle2);

    Bundle bundle3 = new Bundle();
    bundle3.putString("edttext", "9,10,13");

    NewsFeedTab1 fragObj3 = new NewsFeedTab1();
    fragObj3.setArguments(bundle3);

    Bundle bundle4 = new Bundle();
    bundle4.putString("edttext", "11");

    NewsFeedTab1 fragObj4 = new NewsFeedTab1();
    fragObj4.setArguments(bundle4);

    Bundle bundle5 = new Bundle();
    bundle5.putString("edttext", "12");

    NewsFeedTab1 fragObj5 = new NewsFeedTab1();
    fragObj5.setArguments(bundle5);

    SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(fragObj1, "Habari");
    adapter.addFragment(fragObj2, "Kitaifa");
    adapter.addFragment(fragObj3, "Kimataifa");
    adapter.addFragment(fragObj4, "Michezo");
    adapter.addFragment(fragObj5, "Biashara");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The problem is when Pagedapter is started it initialises both tab position 0 and 1 (which from research is normal) which bringings data meant for tab 2 in tab 1. I have tried to implement setUserVisibleHint but i see no difference. I guess setUserVisibleHint  is a suitable solution when having multiple fragments for each tab.

**Fragment**

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (getView() != null) {
        isViewShown = true;
        // fetchdata() contains logic to show data when page is selected mostly asynctask to fill the data

    } else {
        isViewShown = false;
    }
}        
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_feed_tab1, container, false);
    fragView = view;    
     currTab = getArguments().getString("edttext"); 
    if (!isViewShown) {
        loadNewsFeed(isBottom = "0", isTop = "0", lastStart = "0", lastStop = "0");
    }
}
```

How can i eliminate the problem of the mixup on clicked Tab resulting from i guess double call to  start Fragment.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: @propoLis problem is. A request will be made to fetch data for tab 1 and tab 2 simultaneously as a result the fragment will display tab 2 data inplace of tab1 data

Answer (score 0):

For those who may have a similar problem. I found a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20412875/2448688 . 
Basicaly instead of calling volley in OnCreateView it is called in a method fragmentBecameVisible which is implemented in an interface to notify if fragment is visible and only call Volley at this point.